# React Js npm package Datetime component css are not loading

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, webpack-style-loader

I am using react.js for my project. Below is my css configuration in webpack.dev.config file for css loading.

```
{
            test: /\.css$/,
            use: [
              require.resolve('style-loader'),
              {
                loader: require.resolve('css-loader'),
                options: {
                  importLoaders: 1,
                  modules:true,
                  localIdentName:'[name]__[local]__[hash:base64:5]'
                },
              },
              {
                loader: require.resolve('postcss-loader'),
                options: {
                  // Necessary for external CSS imports to work
                  // https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/issues/2677
                  ident: 'postcss',
                  plugins: () => [
                    require('postcss-flexbugs-fixes'),
                    autoprefixer({
                      browsers: [
                        '>1%',
                        'last 4 versions',
                        'Firefox ESR',
                        'not ie < 9', // React doesn't support IE8 anyway
                      ],
                      flexbox: 'no-2009',
                    }),
                  ],
                },
              },
            ],
          }
```

Whenever I want to use css classes means simply import like this `import classes from '../foldername/filename.css';`

Then I use all css classname like below

```
<div className={classes.cssClassName}></div>
```

But now when I use `<Datetime />` from npm package react-datetime it does not loads css automatically.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-datetime.

How can I load Datetime component css in my file ??

I referred many docs in online which they ask me to use like below.

```
            test: /\.css$/,
            use: [
              require.resolve('style-loader'),
              {
                loader: require.resolve('css-loader'),
                options: {
                  importLoaders: 1,
                  modules:false,
                  localIdentName:''
                },
              },
```

Do I have some other way to use the Datetime component with css.

Any Help

Thanks

Comment: this is the [default styles](https://github.com/YouCanBookMe/react-datetime/blob/master/css/react-datetime.css)

Comment: @Qiarash I look this css from the npm react-datetime offical page. But I got stuck in how to import this css in my .js file. I think I have to change my web pack configuration so that it will allow.

Comment: just try `import 'react-datetime/css/react-datetime.css'`

Comment: @Qiarash Thanks for your response. It is not working for me.